# CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE does not work in some devices such as xiaomi, Huawei p10

Tags: colors, android-camera2, effect

I am using camera2 api.
by the way, color effects are not working in some of devices such as xiaomi.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, many phone makers do not properly implement Camera2. Some Samsung phones for example report 1 second as max exposure, but in reality it's 300 ms. NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE also doesn't work for them, but works on Xiaomi.

The only way to reliably get the results you want is use the raw mode and do your own processing...